# JQuery - only last event handler triggers in event delegation series?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, slider, mouseevent

I been trying to build an image slider from scratch that will slide automatically but then go to a certain slide when the corresponding dot at the bottom is clicked.

When I isolate and test each of my event delegation click functions individually, they work great to get the different photos to slide back and forth. But when all functions are together only the 3rd function works. Can you help?

To demonstrate I made a [simple mock-up slider here](http://jsfiddle.net/talker90/bxmemfnw/) which includes the following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {

//DOM cache 
var $slider = $('section');
var $slideContainer = $slider.find('ul');
var $windowWidth = $slider.css('width');
var $windowWidthUnitless = $slider.width();
var $dot1 = $slider.find('#dot-1');
var $dot2 = $slider.find('#dot-2');
var $dot3 = $slider.find('#dot-3');

//config
var width = $windowWidth;
var doubleWidth = $windowWidthUnitless * 2;

$($slider).on('click',$dot1,function() {
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
    $dot1.addClass('filled');
    $dot2.removeClass('filled');
    $dot3.removeClass('filled');
})

$($slider).on('click',$dot2,function() {
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', '-' +width);
    $dot1.removeClass('filled');
    $dot2.addClass('filled');
    $dot3.removeClass('filled');
})

$($slider).on('click',$dot3,function() {
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', "-" +doubleWidth +"px");
    $dot1.removeClass('filled');
    $dot2.removeClass('filled');
    $dot3.addClass('filled');
})

});
```

Acting on this html:

```
<section>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="slide-1"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="slide-2"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="slide-3"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div id="slide-1"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="selected" id="dot-1"></div>
<div id="dot-2"></div>
<div id="dot-3"></div>
```

and CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} /* just my default */

section {
overflow: hidden;
width:400px;
height:400px;
}

section ul {
width:1600px;
}

section li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
float: left;
}

[id*="slide-"] {
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
}

[id*="dot-"] {
float:left;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
border-radius: 20px;
position: relative;
bottom: 45px;
}
```

(if this helps, here's a [more exact but still simplified](http://jsfiddle.net/talker90/mpd0eqpr/) version of my slider, that actually slides automatically as well and is meant to stop and go to a certain slide when a dot is clicked. Again, it only goes to the last slide.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of the `$($slider).on('click',$dotNumber,function() {...}` lines, replace $dotNumber with `'#dot-number'`.

Example: `$($slider).on('click','#dot-1',function() {...}`

I don't know if there's a particular way to pass a jQuery object to specify a child element to target, but I do know that adding the CSS selector as the second parameter will do it. According to the [man page](http://api.jquery.com/on/), the second parameter (if it's not the callback) is a string.